# Binary Tree Find_parent method causing SegFault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

Why this method is causing me a segfault? I tried to re write this in several ways according to my C experience but still nothing good happens.

```
TreeNode *Find_parent(TreeNode *node, int value)
{

  assert(value != NULL);


 if(node->value == value) {
       return NULL;
  }
   if(node->value > value) {
       if(node->left != NULL) {

           if(node->left->value == value) {
              return node;
          } else {
             return Find_parent(node->left, value);
         }
      } else {
          return NULL;
      }
    } else {
          if(node->right != NULL) {

             if(node->right->value == value) {
                return node;
             } else {
                return Find_parent(node->right, value);
           }
        } else {
           return NULL;
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: `assert(value != NULL);` with `int` type value?? Not seems meaningful

Comment: Your indentation is not proper. Good indentation greatly reduces the debugging effort, so follow it properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you copied your original code step by step here, then I think you did this by mistake:

`assert(value != NULL);`

I think you meant to do this:  `assert(node != NULL);`

Basically you have not implemented check for `node` being `NULL`, and when `NULL` node gets dereferenced, it causes Seg-Fault.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But even with your proposition, segfault is still present while doing automated testing. Any other clues?